# Unable to find bug in this C program

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm unable to find bug in this C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 

    struct book 
    { 
        char name ; 
        float price ; 
        int pages ; 
    } ;

    struct book b[3] ;
    int i ; int k;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
    { 
        printf ( "\nEnter name, price and pages: " ) ;
        k = scanf ( "%c %f %d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages ) ;
    } 
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ ) 
        printf ( "\n%c %f %d", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages ) ;
    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

run time:

```
Enter name, price and pages: a 1 1

Enter name, price and pages: b 2 2

Enter name, price and pages:
a 1.000000 1

 7922540190797673100000000000000000.000000 4200368
b 2.000000 2
```

I wanted to give `a 1 1` , `b 2 2`, `c 3 3` as my inputs for each scanfs but it didn't wait for my input in  3rd scanf. Why so? and why did it read my 2nd time input into 3rd elementof array?

Comment: And now you're discovering why NOBODY uses scanf.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Shocked! NOBODY uses scanf?? why?? What exactly is happening here. What am I missing here?

Comment: @walter Nobody uses scanf for processing input from humans.

Comment: scanf doesn't behave well if it doesn't get EXACTLY what it's asking for.  I think what's happening in your case is it's accepting the return at the end of the line as the first character second array, then going off into the weeds from there, as it is wont to do.

Answer (score 8):

Add a [`getchar()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getchar.html) after your `scanf()`

```
 for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
  { 
      printf ( "\nEnter name, price and pages: " ) ;
      k = scanf ( "%c %f %d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages ) ;

      getchar(); //will clear the buffer
  }
```

P.S: [Don't use `scanf()` for `char` entry.](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-60.html)

Answer (score 7):

Unlike the other specifiers, %c when used with scanf does not ignore whitespace. You probably want to make the name fields strings in any case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    struct book 
    { 
        char name[10] ;   // or some suitable size
        float price ; 
        int pages ; 
    } ;

    struct book b[3] ;
    int i ; int k;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
    { 
        printf ( "\nEnter name, price and pages: " ) ;
        k = scanf ( "%s %f %d", b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages ) ;
    } 
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ ) 
        printf ( "\n%s %f %d", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can add `fflush(stdin);` before your scanf.</strike>.

It turns out that you should not use `fflush` on `stdin` because `fflush` is *only* defined to work on output streams. In other words `fflush` has undefined behaviour on input streams.

```
int fflush(FILE *ostream);
```

an extract from the C standard says:

> ostream **points to an output stream** or
>   an update stream in which the most
>   recent operation was not input, the
>   fflush function causes any unwritten
>   data for that stream to be delivered
>   to the host environment to be written
>   to the file; **otherwise, the behavior
>   is undefined.**

Comment: No, you can't - fflush is only defined to work on output streams.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Wrong, although it may work: http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351

Comment: Sure, if you can call fflush(stdin);, but you're taking the chance of demons flying out your nose. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: seems pretty clear that "behavior is undefined" implies "wrong", unless you think that writing programs based on undefined behavior is right.